# Workflow in pimcore not working

Tags: php, pimcore

I have created a workflow in Pimcore using its own documentation tutorial:

https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Workflow_Management/Workflow_Tutorial.html

```
<?php

return [

"workflows" => [
    [

    ],
    [
        "name" => "Product workflow",
        "id" => 8108,
        "workflowSubject" => [
            "types" => ["object"],
            "classes" => [38],
        ],
        "enabled" => true,
        "defaultState" => "opened",
        "defaultStatus" => "new",
        "allowUnpublished" => false,
        "states" => [
            [
                "name" => "opened",
                "label" => "Unfinished product",
                "color" => "#377ea9"
            ],
            [
                "name" => "processing",
                "label" => "Processing",
                "color" => "#d9ef36"
            ],
            [
                "name" => "done",
                "label" => "Finished product",
                "color" => "#28a013"
            ]
        ],
        "statuses" => [
            [
                "name" => "new",
                "label" => "New product",
                "objectLayout" => 1
            ],
            [
                "name" => "rejected",
                "label" => "Rejected product"
            ],
            [
                "name" => "update_contents",
                "label" => "Updating contents step",
            ],
            [
                "name" => "update_picture",
                "label" => "Update the product picture",
                "objectLayout" => 4
            ],
            [
                "name" => "validate_stock_and_price",
                "label" => "Check the quantity and the price",
                "objectLayout" => 5
            ],
            [
                "name" => "contents_preapared",
                "label" => "Contents ready to publish"
            ],
            [
                "name" => "accepted",
                "label" => "Accepted product",
                "elementPublished" => true
            ]
        ],
        "actions" => [
            [
                "name" => "reject",
                "label" => "Reject the product",
                "transitionTo" => [
                    "done" => [
                        "rejected"
                    ]
                ],
                "notes" => [
                    "required" => false
                ]
            ],
            [
                "name" => "process",
                "label" => "Start processing the product",
                "transitionTo" => [
                    "processing" => [
                        "update_contents"
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                "name" => "contents_updated",
                "label" => "Contents up-to-date",
                "transitionTo" => [
                    "processing" => [
                        "update_picture"
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                "name" => "picture_updated",
                "label" => "Picture up-to-date",
                "transitionTo" => [
                    "processing" => [
                        "validate_stock_and_price"
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                "name" => "contents_ready",
                "label" => "Contents are ready to publish",
                "transitionTo" => [
                    "processing" => ["contents_preapared"]
                ],
                "notes" => [
                    "required" => false
                ]
            ],
            [
                "name" => "publish",
                "label" => "Publish the product",
                "transitionTo" => [
                    "done" => [
                        "accepted"
                    ]
                ],
                "additionalFields" => [
                    [
                        "name" => "timeWorked",
                        "fieldType" => "input",
                        "title" => "Time spent",
                        "blankText" => "30m",
                        "required" => true,
                        "setterFn" => null
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "transitionDefinitions" => [
            "new" => [ //this is the starting status, at the moment we can only set the product as rejected or move it to the processing stage
                "validActions" => [
                    "reject" => null,
                    "process" => null
                ]
            ],
            "rejected" => [ //we can only mark rejected project as a new
                "validActions" => [
                    "new" => null
                ]
            ],
            "update_contents" => [ // the product with update_contents status is able to use the contents_updated action
                "validActions" => [
                    "contents_updated" => null
                ]
            ],
            "update_picture" => [ // the product with update_picture status is able to use the picture_updated action
                "validActions" => [
                    "picture_updated" => null
                ]
            ],
            "validate_stock_and_price" => [ //here we can mark cthe product as a ready to the final validation
                "validActions" => [
                    "contents_ready" => null
                ]
            ],
            "contents_preapared" => [ // accept, reject or rollback
                "validActions" => [
                    "process" => null,
                    "reject" => null,
                    "publish" => null
                ]
            ],
            "accepted" => [
                "validActions" => [
                    "reject" => null
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

];

After that I have placed the workflowmanagement.php file in **website/config**

How to trigger this workflow ? I couldn't find **actions** button in the objects I have created.

Other than creating the workflowmanagement.php file what should I do to get the worflowmanagement to work properly in pimcore.

Answer (score 0):

Workflow_management tutorial : Still thier are no new updateion. But you can get your action in this code here:

```
"actions" => [
    [
      "name" => "reject",
      "label" => "Reject the product",
      "transitionTo" => [
          "done" => [
              "rejected"
          ]
      ],
      "notes" => [
          "required" => false
      ]
    ],
    [
      "name" => "process",
      "label" => "Start processing the product",
      "transitionTo" => [
          "processing" => [
              "update_contents"
          ]
      ]
    ]
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Register it in config.yaml file like this:

```
imports:
    - { resource: 'user_workflow.yaml' }
```

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.